# Dealing with message order when using a queue

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, message-queue, messagebroker

I have customer records in Firebase like this:

```
{
  "displayName": "John Doe",
  ...
}
```

I need to create/update/delete them in an Elasticsearch instance when they are created/updated/deleted in Firebase.

I'm trying to deal with potential failed writes to Elasticsearch. I'd like to use a queue like Firebase queue that will retry the write if Elasticsearch is down or can't be reached. However, I'm not sure how to get around potential message order issues.

For example, I write a new record to Firebase and a 'write' message that contains the record is put into a queue to be sent to Elasticsearch. I then delete the record from Firebase. A 'delete' message is put into the queue to be sent to Elasticsearch.

The write message fails for some reason and is put back into the queue. The delete message succeeds. The write message is retried by the queue and this time it succeeds. I now have a record in Elasticsearch that should not be there.

This issue isn't specific to Firebase or Elasticsearch...they just happen to be the tools I'm working with right now. Any advice on how to get around this is much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you need a queuing mechanism that somehow guarantees the order of delivered messages coming from a client.

Comment: I agree. Any suggestions?